# Excel 2010 to PDF using VB

Tags: visual-studio-2010, pdf, excel-2010

I have hundreds of Excel files being saved in a folder. I was wondering how I could write something in Visual Basic to convert these to PDF. Is there a way to call to Excel 2010's Save As function to save them in a different folder? I have checked Google and on here and all I can find is references to third party applications.

Answer (score 2):

```
 Dim excel As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    excel = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    Dim tmpWorkbooks As Workbooks
    tmpWorkbooks = excel.Workbooks
Dim wb As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
    wb = tmpWorkbooks.Open(pathOfExcelFile)
    excel.Visible = False
  wb.Activate()
wb.ExportAsFixedFormat(XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, fileName, , , , 1, 1, False, )
```

Answer (score 2):

In Excel 2010 you can use this VBA code:

```
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:="C:\Temp\Workbook1.pdf", _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=True, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

Of course you need to set `Filename`to the correct path for your machine, and as it uses `ActiveSheet` I suppose you need to iterate through your sheets if you have more than one in your workbooks. See [the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.exportasfixedformat.aspx) for more details on the ExportAsFixedFormat function.

Comment: Just wanted to comment since I am new and cant vote up. This really helped a lot and the MSDN article was the icing on the cake. Thanks TREB!